# Images, Video and Text in Android WebView as Book Pages

Tags: android, html

I have a ebook single HTML page having text, video and audios, which I want to display as book pages able to slide left & right to view the previous page and next page respectively.

1. How do I slice the data to show for a particular page for both orientations ?
2. I am trying to use WebView for it. Any other possible options?
3. Is HTML is a best way to store the content? Other options?

Cheers,
Prateek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such animations can't be done using only HTML. You can use Flash for doing so and then can embed that to the HTML codes.